# I need to understand bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Hi i didnt find good information on the web about bipartite graps.

For example does the sum of the degrees on both sides have to be equal? or a bipartite graph G (with side A & B) whose number of edges is 27 can have sum(deg(A)) = 24? or it must be 27 too? (so we will get that 2|E|=54)

How can i check if it has no odd circles? never seen a formula for this

Thanks in advance

Comment: The outdegree of $A$ has to be the number of edges, of course (if it were lower, were would the other edges be?). Hence the degree of both parts have to be equal.

Comment: I don't think your comment is right; consider a graph with two nodes separated by a directed edge from one to the other (e.g. v->w). This is clearly bipartite, but the outdegrees of the partitions do not equal to the number of edges (e.g. A={v} and B={w} and outdeg(B) is not 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A graph $G\equiv\left(V,E\right)$ is bipartite if there exist disjoint sets $A,B$ satisfying $V=A\cup B$ s.t. for all $a,a^{\prime}\in A$, $\left(a,a^{\prime}\right)\notin E$ and for all $b,b^{\prime}\in B$, $\left(b,b^{\prime}\right)\notin E$.

From this it follows that outdeg$\left(A\right)$ $=$ indeg$\left(B\right)$ and vice-versa (convince yourself of this).

A graph $G$ is bipartite if and only if it does not contain an odd cycle. Suppose a graph contains an odd cycle. Since there is no way to make a bipartite subgraph out of the odd cycle (convince yourself of this), $G$ is not bipartite. The proof of the converse is slightly more involved: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Graph_is_Bipartite_iff_No_Odd_Cycles